# Is RedHat provide openLDAP package with RHEL5?

Tags: openldap, rhel5

My software needs system openLDAP libraries. Is RedHat provide openLDAP package (with libraries)with RHEL5 or not?

Answer (score 0):

*RHEL5* does not comes with *openLDAP* you need to install it manually.

Comment: Thanks tejesh. Redhat provide any other LDAP libraries with OS,

Answer (score 0):

With RHEL5 DVD comes with *openldap, openldap-servers, openldap-devel, nss_ldap* and *openldap-clients* RPMs.